# If a unitary is such that $U|0\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$, what is $U|1\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-gate, unitarity

If we have a $U$ (unitary with all real entries) such that:

$U|0\rangle =a|0\rangle +b|1\rangle$

What is $U|1\rangle=?$

I know: the definition of what it means to be unitary ie. $U^\dagger U=UU^\dagger =I$

I've worked out: for $U|1\rangle=c|0\rangle+d|1\rangle$ must satisfy $ac+bd=0$ (by taking it's dagger and multiplying it for the constants).

Is this the only information we can derive? How can I write $U|1\rangle$?

Comment: My unitary has all real entries.

Comment: I see. Well, then you still need the normalization.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Lock, I think he means that $|a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1$

Comment: Oh. Yes, I have considered this already but was not able to use this to derive anything new.

Comment: I am looking for $ab+cd$ and $a^2+c^2$ (or their counterparts) particularly.

Comment: The 2x2 real unitary (=orthogonal) matrices are parametrized by one parameter only, and are of the form [cos(x) sin(x) ; -sin(x) cos(x)], and the same with the 2nd row multiplied with -1.  And you have 3 conditions for 4 variables.  All good.

Comment: It seems you are assuming that U acts on a single qubit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have $U|1\rangle=e^{i\phi}(b^*|0\rangle-a^*|1\rangle)$ (and for real entries, $e^{i\phi}=\pm1$). This condition follows automatically from
$$
\langle 0|U^\dagger U |1\rangle=0
$$
-- this is exactly the condition you describe -- together with the fact that $U|0\rangle$ and $U|1\rangle$ must have the same normalization,
$$
\langle k|U^\dagger U |k\rangle=1
$$
for $k=0,1$. (This also means that $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.)

This is the only condition, since now you have ensured that all matrix elements of $U^\dagger U$ are of the correct form.

Answer (score 4):

The general form of a 2x2 unitary matrix is:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & \beta \\
-e^{i\phi}\beta^* & e^{i\phi}\alpha^*
\end{pmatrix},
$$

with the constraint that $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2$ = 1.

Since you say that $U|0\rangle = U\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$, we have that $\alpha = a$ and $-e^{i\phi}\beta^* = b$.

Therefore, the ***most*** we can say about the bottom-right corner is that $d=e^{i\phi}a^*$, and the most we can say about the  top-right corner is $c=\beta = -b^* e^{i\phi}$.

So you have: $U|1\rangle = e^{i\phi}b^*|0\rangle - e^{i\phi}a^*|1\rangle$.
We therefore do not have enough information to determine the phase $\phi$, but since you only ask how to write $U|1\rangle$ we don't need $\phi$ because it enters our expression for $U|1\rangle$ only as a *global phase*.

**In conclusion:** If all we know is $U|0\rangle = a|0\rangle = b|1\rangle$, then we can say that $U|1\rangle = b^*|0\rangle -a^*|1\rangle$, which is correct up to a global phase.

Answer (score 1):

The columns of a unitary matrix must be orthonormal! So, in this case, since you know the image of $|0\rangle$ under $U$, it must be that $U|1\rangle$ is the unit vector orthogonal to $U|0\rangle=a|0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$.